# AWS-SDK NodeJS : How to check if DynamoDB config is right and its up

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Could anyone please help me to find out how can I check about validity of configuration and status of DynamoDB, consider following sample code

```
function initConfig() {
    AWS.config.update({
        region: REGION,
        endpoint: HOST+":"+PORT,
        username: USERNAME,
        password: PASSWORD
    });
     dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
     docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
        apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
        httpOptions:{
            connectTimeout:1000
        }
    });
}
```

In above code where can I check about validity of dynamodb host and port, and before making any db call check if its up ? I have tried to search over awsdocs but went unlucky. Any help in terms of redirection / sample code would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.